# Localization background image

Tags: css

i have a css file as follow:

```
 .header {  
 background-image: url('http://demo.com/image/bg.jpg');      
font-size: 100px;
}
```

is display correctly

but need to Localization  image file
i try is not work

```
.header {    
background-image: url('image/bg.jpg);        
font-size: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: are you sure the file is in the correct place? `image/bg.jpg` will assume that the folder `image` is located where your CSS file is. Also localizations means something different, please use location, or file path

Comment: Is the folder `image` is in the same directory where your html page is?

Comment: The path in `url()` is relative to the css file, not to the page. Try `url('/image/bg.jpg');`. Also, you're missing the `'` after filename.

Comment: my css file in  /css
my background image in /image/bg.jpg @N. Ivanov

Comment: then you should use smth like `"../images/bg.jpg"`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your css file like style.css is on css directory then the location will be like the following:

```
.header {    
   background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');        
   font-size: 100px; 
}
```

And if your css file like style.cs is on the root directory then the location will be like the following:

```
.header {    
   background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');        
   font-size: 100px; 
}
```

Try this hope it will work if work please click on accept button